# Не компилируется // ошибка: 'statusCell' has not been declared

Tags: qt, c++

Пишу угру GoMoku среда qt
    есть 2 класса 
gomoku и butmoku(унаследован от QPushButton и добавлены поля одно из них из gomoku)
все работало 
пока не понадобилось создать слот который бы вызвал метод из gomoku c параметром (ссылка на butmoku) чтоб добавить такой пораметр необходимо уже подключить в gomoku butmoku.
После чего выплывает ошибка

```
D:\Project\GoMoku-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK_________\..\GoMoku\butmoku.h:18: ошибка: 'statusCell' has not been declared
```

код программы

```
#ifndef GOMOKU_H
#define GOMOKU_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include "butmoku.h"

enum statusCell{empty,X,O};
enum statusGame{win,lose,draw};

class GoMoku : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    private:
    int size;
    statusCell **array;
public:
    explicit GoMoku(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void initArray(int _size);
    void initButton();
    void SetSize(int _size);
    int GetSize();
    statusCell GetStatusArray(int _i,int _j);
    void SetStatusArray(int _i,int _j,statusCell _stat);
    statusGame check();
    ~GoMoku();
signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // GOMOKU_H

#ifndef BUTMOKU_H
#define BUTMOKU_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include "gomoku.h"

class ButMoku : public QPushButton
{
private:
    statusCell stat;
    int i,j;
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ButMoku(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ButMoku(int _i,int _j,statusCell _stat,QWidget *parent = 0);
    void refresh();
signals:

public slots:
   void slotclic();
};

#endif // BUTMOKU_H
```

Ps спасибо всем зарание

Comment: @Дима Partizan, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @Дима Partizan, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

И? Вы пытаетесь использовать statusCell в файле в котором он не объявлен, вынесите ваши энумераторы в отдельный файл, и подключите этот файл в оба хэдэра.

Comment: Или, судя по этому конкретному случаю, можно перенести объявление `enum statusCell` в начало `butmoku.h`.

Comment: Да, но уж лучше все-таки в отдельный файл, как-то чище будет.

Comment: Была такая идея. наверное так и сделаю но объясните если можете если я НЕ добовляю #include "gomoku.h" в butmoku.h то в butmoku.h statusCell виден.
как только я добовляю в gomoku.h, #include "butmoku.h" начинает ругаться.
Ведь если я не путаю #ifndef #define команды препроцессора не дают зациклится линковшику именно если хэдеры вызывают друг друга. 
Я только учу с++ но мне кажется нужен какойто параметр

Comment: ммм... если я переношу определние то уже начинает ругаться в gomoku...
Наверное 99.9% надо выносить Спасибо вам!

Comment: епт, да, не заметил второй файл сразу.